# how to hide the button by status in javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have code like this

```html
<script>
document.getElementById("view").style.visibility="hidden";{
var a="<?php echo $status[0]->status;?>"
if(!a==0){
.hide();}
});
</script>
```

how to hide button without click?

Comment: What do you mean "without click"? The current code would hide the element with id "view" immediately on page load (assuming that script element appears after the element in question). So move it to inside the if block. And fix the JS syntax errors.

Comment: yes,the button is hidden when status=1

Answer (score 1):

Try like this-

```html
<script>
    var btn = document.getElementById("view");
    var a="<?php echo $status[0]->status;?>";
    if(!a==0){
        btn.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `!a==0`? Should be `!(a==0)` or, better, `a != 0`. (Or, probably better still, don't compare a string with a number.)

Comment: Thanks. I know it, but as I don't know what will be found from php so I left the condition same as the question.

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner way of doing this would be to set the status value in a hidden variable and in JS you just compare with the value of the hidden variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can use `.css` attribute:

```
<script>
        var a="<?php echo $status[0]->status;?>"
        if(!a==0)
        {
           $("#view").css('display','none');
        }
</script>
```

**OR** you can **hide()** like this:

```
<script>
        var a="<?php echo $status[0]->status;?>"
        if(!a==0)
        {
                $("#view").hide();
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this.

**HTML**

```
< input type="button" id="view">
```

**JS**

```
var a= 1; //"<?php echo $status[0]->status;?>"
if(a != 0){
$("#view").hide();
};
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2uqu3gk9/)

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("view").style.visibility="<?php echo $status[0]->status==0?"none":"block"; ?>";
</script>
```